# Checkbox is unchecked while I go back to the ui-view in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

I have three view templates in angular js and three forms in them respectively. In the first view there is a form with checkbox options. When I go to second view and want to return back to the first view the checkbox is reset to unchecked.

What is the best solution for this to remain the checkbox checked?
I have an object courseContent and the answer is saved there in courseContent.optQ_1.answer

I have used the following code in first ui-view template:

```
<div>
<div class="col-md-8">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            Course Content and Organization
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <form name="courseContentOrg">
                <ol>
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <li><strong>The course objectives were clear</strong></li>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <ul class="sub-list">
                            <li><input type="radio" name="optQ_1" ng-model="optQ_1" value="strongly_agree"
                                       ng-required="!optQ_1" ng-checked="{{ courseContent.optQ_1.answer == 'strongly_agree' ? 'checked' : ''}}"> Strongly Agree
                            </li>
                            <li><input type="radio" name="optQ_1" ng-model="optQ_1" value="uncertain"
                                       ng-required="!optQ_1" ng-checked="{{ courseContent.optQ_1.answer == 'uncertain' ? 'checked' : ''}}">
                                Uncertain
                            </li>
                            <li><input type="radio" name="optQ_1" ng-model="optQ_1" value="disagree"
                                       ng-required="!optQ_1" ng-checked="{{ courseContent.optQ_1.answer == 'disagree' ? 'checked' : ''}}">
                                Disagree
                            </li>
                            <li><input type="radio" name="optQ_1" ng-model="optQ_1" value="strongly_disagree"
                                       ng-required="!optQ_1" ng-checked="{{ courseContent.optQ_1.answer == 'strongly_disagree' ? 'checked' : ''}}"> Strongly Disagree
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <li><strong>The Course workload was manageable</strong></li>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <ul class="sub-list">
                            <li><input type="radio" name="optQ_2" ng-required="!optQ_2" ng-model="optQ_2" value="strongly_agree"> Strongly Agree</li>
                            <li><input type="radio" name="optQ_2" ng-required="!optQ_2" ng-model="optQ_2" value="agree"> Agree</li>
                            <li><input type="radio" name="optQ_2" ng-required="!optQ_2" ng-model="optQ_2" value="uncertain"> Uncertain</li>
                            <li><input type="radio" name="optQ_2" ng-required="!optQ_2" ng-model="optQ_2" value="disagree"> Disagree</li>
                            <li><input type="radio" name="optQ_2" ng-required="!optQ_2" ng-model="optQ_2" value="strongly_disagree"> Strongly Disagree</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <li><strong>The Course was well organized (e.g. timely access to materials, notification of
                            changes, etc.)</strong></li>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <ul class="sub-list">
                            <li><input type="radio" name="optQ_3" ng-required="!optQ_3" ng-model="optQ_3" value="strongly_agree"> Strongly Agree</li>
                            <li><input type="radio" name="optQ_3" ng-required="!optQ_3" ng-model="optQ_3" value="agree"> Agree</li>
                            <li><input type="radio" name="optQ_3" ng-required="!optQ_3" ng-model="optQ_3" value="uncertain"> Uncertain</li>
                            <li><input type="radio" name="optQ_3" ng-required="!optQ_3" ng-model="optQ_3" value="disagree"> Disagree</li>
                            <li><input type="radio" name="optQ_3" ng-required="!optQ_3" ng-model="optQ_3" value="strongly_disagree"> Strongly Disagree</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <li><strong>Comments</strong></li>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <textarea rows="4" name="commentsQ_1" ng-model="commentsQ_1" placeholder="Write your comments here"
                          class="form-control"></textarea>
                    </div>

                </ol>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-footer">
            <a href="#studentsContribution" class="next btn btn-primary" ng-click="submitCourseContent()"
               ng-disabled="courseContentOrg.$invalid">Next</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">Evaluation for:</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <h4 class="borderBottom">Department:</h4>
            <div>{{ basicInfo.dept }}</div>

            <h4 class="borderBottom">Semester:</h4>
            <div>{{ basicInfo.semester }}</div>

            <h4 class="borderBottom">Subject:</h4>
            <div>{{ basicInfo.subject }}</div>

            <h4 class="borderBottom">Teacher:</h4>
            <div>{{ basicInfo.teacher }}</div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

here is app.js

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ["ngRoute"]);
app.controller('basicInfo', function ($scope, basicInfoService) {
$scope.showViews = false;
$scope.basicForm = false;
console.log($scope.basicInfo);
$scope.departments = [
    {name: 'Architecture & Panning'},
    {name: 'Chemical Engineering'},
    {name: 'Computer Systems Engineering'},
    {name: 'Electronic Engineeering'},
    {name: 'Energy & Environment Engineering'},
    {name: 'Industrial Engineering & Management'},
    {name: 'Petroleum & Gas Engineering'},
    {name: 'Metallurgy & Material Engineering'},
    {name: 'Telecommunication Engineering'},
];

$scope.basicInfo = basicInfoService.getBasicInfo();

$scope.subjects = [
    {code: 'DLD', title: 'Digital Logic Design'},
    {code: 'ITC', title: 'Introduction to computer'},
    {code: 'SCQ', title: 'Sequential Circuit Design'},
];

$scope.teachers = [
    {name: 'Fahad Iqbal'},
    {name: 'Shameem-ur-Rehman'},
    {name: 'Dr. Munaf Rashid'}
];
$scope.surveyFor = function () {
    console.log('hi');
};

$scope.submitForm = function () {

    $scope.showViews = true;
    $scope.basicForm = true;
    var basicInfo = {
        'dept': $scope.dept,
        'semester': $scope.semester,
        'subject': $scope.sub,
        'teacher': $scope.teach
    };

    basicInfoService.addBasicInfo(basicInfo);
}
});

app.controller("courseContentOrg", function ($scope, basicInfoService) {
$scope.basicInfo = basicInfoService.getBasicInfo();
$scope.courseContent = basicInfoService.getQuestionaire().courseContent;
console.log($scope.courseContent);
$scope.submitCourseContent = function () {

    var courseContentOrg = {
        'optQ_1': {
            'question': 'The course objectives were clear',
            'answer': $scope.optQ_1
        },
        'optQ_2': {
            'question': 'The Course workload was manageable',
            'answer': $scope.optQ_2
        },
        'optQ_3': {
            'question': 'The Course was well organized (e.g. timely access to materials, notification of changes, etc.)',
            'answer': $scope.optQ_3
        },
        'commentsQ_1': {
            'question': 'Comments',
            'answer': $scope.commentsQ_1
        }
    };

    basicInfoService.addCourseContentChoices(courseContentOrg);
}
});

app.controller("studentsContributions", function ($scope, basicInfoService)     {
$scope.basicInfo = basicInfoService.getBasicInfo();
});

app.service('basicInfoService', function () {
var basicInfo;
var questionaire = {
    'courseContent': 0,
    'studentsContributions': 0
};

var addBasicInfo = function (newObj) {
    basicInfo = {};
    basicInfo = newObj;
};

var addCourseContentChoices = function (newObj) {
    questionaire.courseContent = {};
    questionaire.courseContent = newObj;
};

var getQuestionaire = function () {
    return questionaire;
};

var getBasicInfo = function () {
    return basicInfo;
};

return {
    addBasicInfo: addBasicInfo,
    getBasicInfo: getBasicInfo,
    addCourseContentChoices: addCourseContentChoices,
    getQuestionaire: getQuestionaire
}
});

app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider
    .when("/courseContentOrg", {
        templateUrl: "views/questions/courseContentOrg.html",
        controller: 'courseContentOrg'
    })
    .when("/", {
        templateUrl: "views/basicInfo.html",
        controller: 'basicInfo'
    })
    .when("/studentsContribution", {
        templateUrl: "views/questions/studentsContributions.html",
        controller: 'studentsContributions'
    })
    .otherwise("/", {
        templateUrl: "views/basicInfo.html",
        controller: 'basicInfo'
    })
});

app.factory("basicData", function () {
return {};
});
```

See in the attachment. in inspect element it is working but the checkbox is unchecked?

[first ui-view template snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tMYy.png)

Comment: add your code sample please

Comment: @jos code updated

Answer (score 1):

Before you transition to another state, you would need to store the values of those check boxes somewhere. Since you already have everything in place in your `basicInfoService`, that is a good place to store those values. Also, you can use other storage options.

So, in your `courseContentOrg` controller, you will need to have something like this (here I'm using the version with your `basicInfoService`, but you can use whatever storage option you want, though this one is preferable):

```
var storedQuestionare = basicInfoService.getQuestionare();
$scope.optQ_1 = storedQuestionare .optQ_1 || default_value; //you need to put the default value here if you didn't store your values yet (for example, first time activating this state).
//rest of the values that you need ($scope.optQ_2, $scope.optQ_3, ...)
```

Comment: you are right but I am already store the checkboxes data in courseContentOrg controller.

    '$scope.courseContent = basicInfoService.getQuestionaire().courseContent;'

Comment: I fetch the checkboxes data also in the console in the first ui-view but the checkbox is not changing to checked. you can see the screen shot in my question also

Comment: Ok, but you are not assigning values from `$scope.courseContent` to your properties `$scope.optQ_1` (and 2 and 3). This needs to happen in order for them to be shown in your checkboxes through `ng-model`.

Comment: I have assigned scope variable also still the checkboxes are unchecked when I go back.